# How to support Gmail in my Outlook add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

My add-in is disabled in Gmail inboxes on my Outlook for Mac app. How can I enable it? Can someone direct me to some documentation or information regarding this issue? The review team directed me to an email address I should contact, but I'm not getting any answers anymore.
My manifest file is https://attacksimulator-plugins.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/outlook/manifest-dist.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add-ins are only supported when google account is synchronised to Microsoft Cloud.
Gmail account configured using IMAP/POP cannot use add-ins.

Useful links:

[Add a Gmail account to Outlook and sync to Microsoft Cloud.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081)

[Install an add-in from the Office Store](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-an-office-add-in-for-outlook-1ee261f9-49bf-4ba6-b3e2-2ba7bcab64c8)

Comment: I have experienced the same issues. Could you please suggest how I synchronize my Gmail account to Microsoft?